# what is difference between empty($_POST['gender']) && $_POST['gender'] == ""

Tags: php

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Your not connected".mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("detail") or die("Select Database First");
        $error = false;
    //    $password = md5($_POST['password']);
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        if (empty($_POST['student_name']))
        {
            $error = true;
            $stud_error = "You can't leave this empty. ";
        }
        if (empty($_POST['user_name']) && $_POST['user_name'] == "")
        {
            $error = true;
            $user_error = "You can't leave this empty. ";
        } 
        if (empty($_POST['password']) && $_POST['password'] == "")
        {
            $error = true;
            $passError = "You can't leave this empty. ";
        }
        if (empty($_POST['confirm_password']) && $_POST['confirm_password'] == "")
        {
            $error = true;
            $confirmError = "Confirm your password here. ";
        }
        if (empty($_POST['gender']) && $_POST['gender'] == "")
        {
             $error = true;
             $genderError = "You can't leave this empty.";
        }
        if (empty($_POST['Year']) && $_POST['Year'] == "")
        {
            if (empty($_POST['Month']) && $_POST['Month'] == "")
            {
                if(empty($_POST['Day']) && $_POST['Day'] == "")
                {
                        $error =true;
                        $birthError = "You can't leave this empty.";
                }     
            }
        }   
        if (empty($_POST['email']) && $_POST['email'] == "")
        {
            $error =true;
            $emailError="You can't leave this empty.";            
        }           
        if ($error == false)
        {
           $password = md5($_POST['password']);

            $date = $_POST['Year'].'-'.$_POST['Month'].'-'.$_POST['Day']; 
            $sex = $_POST['gender'];
            $abc="INSERT INTO student (stud_name,username,stud_pass,sex,birthdate,email)VALUES('$_POST[student_name]','$_POST[user_name]','$password','$sex','$date','$_POST[email]')";
            mysql_query($abc);   
        }
    }
?>
<body>
dkjkjdk
</body>
```

Comment: ok thanks... but what is difference

Comment: it's your choice, but you should check for variable also with "isset" so > 
if(!isset($_POST['var']) || empty($_POST['var']))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (empty($_POST['user_name']) && $_POST['user_name'] == ""))
```

That's a foolish if condition, kill the second one. Read what the manual has to say

**[empty](http://php.net/empty)**

> Returns FALSE if var exists and has a non-empty, non-zero value. Otherwise returns TRUE.
>
> The following things are considered to be empty:
>
> •"" (an empty string)
>
> •0 (0 as an integer)
>
> •0.0 (0 as a float)
>
> •"0" (0 as a string)
>
> •NULL
>
> •FALSE
>
> •array() (an empty array)
>
> •$var; (a variable declared, but without a value)

That condition, at its best, is redundant. Its just like saying if a glass is empty and if it has no water :)   (it can't have water if its empty so why check?)

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, a variable is empty, if

- empty string: "" (eg. generated by: `$var = "";`)
- 0 (int)
- 0.0 (float)
- "0" (a zero as string, lol)
- NULL
- FALSE (boolean)
- an empty array (eg. generated by: `$var = array();`)
- variable with no value defined (eg. generated by: `$var;`)

So be careful.

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Answer (score 0):

empty() is php function which returns boolean value(Returns FALSE if var exists and has a non-empty, non-zero value. Otherwise returns TRUE.)  so when you are calling
empty($_POST['student_name']) means if student name field return null value then empty function will return true its basically checking whether your post is acquiring the data or null